# invalid input-output audio device freeswitch

Tags: voip, freeswitch

i am using freeswitch for a VOIP application. after loading mod_portaudio, **pa devlist** results blank , pa call 9999 and pa call 9996 reasult **mod_portaudio.c:2453 Error invalid output audio device.** . Can anyone please help me why these errors are coming. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install alsa dev package, then reconfigure and recompile freeswitch.

In ubuntu package name is libasound2-dev.

Some more info here: http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html